# Escape vue components in html

Tags: vue.js

I'm struggling to make a table with `component` / `HTML example` pairs.

Here's the example of what I did (it doesn't work):

```
<td>
    <vm-three-state-checkbox-filter 
        name="three-checkbox"
    ></vm-three-state-checkbox-filter>
</td>
<td v-pre>
    <pre>
        <vm-three-state-checkbox-filter 
            name="three-checkbox"
        ></vm-three-state-checkbox-filter>
    </pre>
</td>
```

And here is the result:
[image: Wrong vue escape]
One the left you can see the rendered component, on the right i **expect** to see raw html instead of nothingness I'm presented with.

I can specify the escaped HTML as string in `data` and that would work (vue escapes strings by default), but I'd prefer to do it in template.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The v-pre directive keeps Vue from compiling anything inside that element.

So your `<vm-three-state-checkbox-filter>` element stays in the browser as it is in the template, and as that is not a valid HTML element, the browser displays: nothing.

v-pre does not HTML-escape anything for you. It only keeps Vue from compiling the Vue-template-code stuff - components, directives, mustache `{{}}` tags.

You could probably write a small custom directive (with the `terminal: true` [option](http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#terminal) enabled) that would convert the HTML elements inside into an escaped string, but that's not something I can throw together on the spot.

Answer (score 1):

HTML code not escaping with  tag.